# PyTorch nn.Linear layer output nan on well formed input and weights

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

(repo for bug: https://github.com/zihualiu/pytorch_linear_bug)

I recently ran into a weird bug in Pytorch and I hope you can help me. In one of my networks I have a fully connected layer denoted as net.fc_h1. However during training, I realized this layer is outputing NaNs before activation. So I put it in pdb, hoping that it will yield me something. below is the logs:

```
# in network declaration:
def forward(self, obs):
    z1 = self.fc_h1(obs)
    if np.isnan(np.sum(z1.data.numpy())):
        pdb.set_trace()
    h1 = F.tanh(z1)
    ...
```

The NaN is indeed captured, but I realized in pdb if you ran the operation again, the result would be something salient:

```
(Pdb) z1.sum()
Variable containing:
nan
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]

(Pdb) self.fc_h1(obs).sum()
Variable containing:
771.5120
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]
```

When I checked to see if either my input or weights contains NaN, I get the following:
    (Pdb) self.fc_h1.weight.max()
    Variable containing:
     0.2482
    [torch.FloatTensor of size 1]

```
(Pdb) self.fc_h1.weight.mean()
Variable containing:
1.00000e-03 *
  1.7761
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]

(Pdb) self.fc_h1.weight.min()
Variable containing:
-0.2504
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]

(Pdb) obs.max()
Variable containing:
 6.9884
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]

(Pdb) obs.min()
Variable containing:
-6.7855
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]

(Pdb) obs.mean()
Variable containing:
1.00000e-02 *
 -1.5033
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1] 
(Pdb) self.fc_h1.bias.max()
Variable containing:
 0.2482
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]

(Pdb) self.fc_h1.bias.mean()
Variable containing:
1.00000e-03 *
  3.9104
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]

(Pdb) self.fc_h1.bias.min()
Variable containing:
-0.2466
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1]
```

It seems both the input, weight and bias are all in good shape. Any insight on how a linear layer can yield NaN if everything is well formed?

EDIT: More weirdness
So I tried to run the forward pass again, interestingly, multiple forward passes gives me different results:

```
(Pdb) self.fc_h1(obs)
Variable containing:
 2.2321e-01 -6.2586e-01 -1.9004e-01  ...  -4.2521e-01  8.6175e-01  8.6866e-01
-7.2699e-02  7.8234e-01 -5.8862e-01  ...   2.4041e-01 -1.7577e-01  6.9928e-01
-7.2699e-02  7.8234e-01 -5.8862e-01  ...   2.4041e-01 -1.7577e-01  6.9928e-01
                ...                   ⋱                   ...
-6.4686e-02 -1.5819e+00  5.7410e-01  ...  -6.4127e-01  5.2837e-01 -1.3166e+00
 3.9214e-01  2.8727e-01 -5.5699e-01  ...  -8.3164e-01 -5.1795e-01 -3.7637e-01
-9.6061e-01  1.4780e-01  5.3614e-02  ...  -1.5042e+00  6.0759e-02 -3.6862e-01
[torch.FloatTensor of size 4096x170]

(Pdb) self.fc_h1(obs)
Variable containing:
 2.2321e-01 -6.2586e-01 -1.9004e-01  ...  -4.2521e-01  8.6175e-01  8.6866e-01
-7.2699e-02  7.8234e-01 -5.8862e-01  ...   2.4041e-01 -1.7577e-01  6.9928e-01
-7.2699e-02  7.8234e-01 -5.8862e-01  ...   2.4041e-01 -1.7577e-01  6.9928e-01
                ...                   ⋱                   ...
        nan         nan         nan  ...          nan  5.2837e-01 -1.3166e+00
        nan         nan         nan  ...          nan -5.1795e-01 -3.7637e-01
        nan         nan         nan  ...          nan  6.0759e-02 -3.6862e-01
[torch.FloatTensor of size 4096x170]
```

I'm not using GPU either, just CPU.

Comment: What is `h1` in your first code snippet? Edit: I mean in the line `if np.isnan(np.sum(h1.data.numpy())):`, which appears to be before `h1` is first defined.

Comment: @nnnmmm sorry thats a typo, should just be z1

Comment: It's really weird. Could you reduce it to a minimal self-contained example for us to run?

Comment: @nnnmmm, I tried... I tried to create a very minimal example by pulling out the tensors and network state_dict. Here is the repo: https://github.com/zihualiu/pytorch_linear_bug

Comment: I ran bug.py 20 times and it always only said "everything is fine". Python 3.5.2, and PyTorch 0.3.0.post4, like you. How did you install PyTorch? Edit: I'm asking because it's reminiscent of my first question on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371017/random-nan-errors-when-importing-matplotlib-pyplot

Comment: So I tried installing pytorch from source, conda and pip. none of them worked. However, when I changed to a different work station just now, the bug seems to disappear. So I think it might just be an issue with some of my environment setup. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: Have you tried weight/batch normalization. MSE loss with MLP's can easily lead to weights under/overflow ?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was copying over code from the RNN name categorization example. I added the optimizer and criterion pattern whereas the example was doing things manually and updating weights by hand. I accidentally added a momentum value to the optimizer and that was what caused my problem. Setting momentum to the default value of `0` fixed it.